# SQL grouping by all the columns

Tags: sql

Is there any way to group by all the columns of a table without specifying the column names?  Like:

```
select * from table group by *
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why would this be a meaningless question?  Seems like something that any beginner sql programmer might ask.

Comment: This would be useful when querying a hive table where rows with null values are not counted when querying `select count(distinct *) from blah`

Answer (score 65):

### The DISTINCT Keyword

I believe what you are trying to do is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM MyFooTable;
```

If you group by all columns, you are just requesting that duplicate data be removed.

For example a table with the following data:

```
 id |     value      
----+----------------
  1 | foo
  2 | bar
  1 | foo
  3 | something else
```

If you perform the following query which is essentially the same as `SELECT * FROM MyFooTable GROUP BY *` if you are assuming * means all columns:

`SELECT * FROM MyFooTable GROUP BY id, value;`

```
 id |     value      
----+----------------
  1 | foo
  3 | something else
  2 | bar
```

It removes all duplicate values, which essentially makes it semantically identical to using the DISTINCT keyword with the exception of the ordering of results. For example:

`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM MyFooTable;`

```
 id |     value      
----+----------------
  1 | foo
  2 | bar
  3 | something else
```

Comment: i think that is not correct. if use row_number() over something, the distinct count more.

if i have one x_code which have two y_code by join, the "distinct" brings me 2 rows and count two times over row_number(), but if i use group by correctily only brings me one.

I'm going through it!

I need a sequencial integer registry and "distinct" count me 2 times on x_code.

Comment: This misses a few important cases such as UDAF's

Comment: Using DISTINCT is not always possible directly. If a query contains the ORDER  BY clause, then one might get an error:

'ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list'

The only solution in this situation is a nested query AFAIK.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using SqlServer the distinct keyword should work for you. (Not sure about other databases)

```
declare @t table (a int , b int)

insert into @t (a,b) select 1, 1
insert into @t (a,b) select 1, 2
insert into @t (a,b) select 1, 1

select distinct * from @t
```

results in

```
a b
1 1
1 2
```

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to do counts and sums over full resultset. I achieved grouping by all with `GROUP BY 1=1`.

Comment: I don't know how this works but it's brilliant and exactly what I needed. Is this trick documented somewhere and it is supported by all major relational DBs?

Answer (score 6):

nope.  are you trying to do some aggregation?  if so, you could do something like this to get what you need

```
;with a as
(
     select sum(IntField) as Total
     from Table
     group by CharField
)
select *, a.Total
from Table t
inner join a
on t.Field=a.Field
```

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: no.  GROUP BY clauses intrinsically require order to the way they arrange your results.  A different order of field groupings would lead to different results.

Specifying a wildcard would leave the statement open to interpretation and unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: "open to interpretation" This is easily addressed by specifying the natural order of the columns - i.e. the order in which they are defined.   A wildcard syntax would be a useful feature.

Comment: As an implicit convention, it would *still* be unpredictable and dependant on the order specified in the `select` clause. As a feature might make sense, but am not sure it is compatible with SQL theoretical model.

Comment: @Kamafeather That's not a good argument, since e.g. NULLs are not compatible with the "SQL theoretical model". In the results of an OUTER JOIN, they mean "not applicable" instead of the theoretical "missing data". Even Dr. Codd himself broke down and [admitted that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#:~:text=inadequate), so here we are with the practical (not theoretical) everyday meaning of NULL. As a long time database developer, I'd also love to have GROUP BY * (or similar) that does indeed depend on the order of the fields (and only those fields) listed in the SELECT clause.

Answer (score 3):

Some databases support `GROUP BY ALL`, such as Snowflake ([see documentation here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/group-by#label-group-by-all-columns)).

> **GROUP BY ALL**
>
> Specifies that all items in the SELECT list that do not use aggregate functions should be used for grouping.

It's great to simplify some queries.

Before:

```sql
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, SUM(price)
FROM table
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9
```

AFTER:

```sql
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, SUM(price)
FROM table
GROUP BY ALL
```

Answer (score 1):

No because this fundamentally means that you will not be grouping anything.  If you group by all columns (and have a properly defined table w/ a unique index) then `SELECT * FROM table` is essentially the same thing as `SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY *`.

Comment: Of course, if you *don't* have a unique index, SELECT * FROM table is *not* the same as SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY *. In that case, you can accomplish this using SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table.

Comment: Having duplicate rows is a common thing you have to deal when inheriting projects - so I don't think that it is safe to assume someone would never want to remove duplicate rows.

Comment: There is another case... SELECT t1.*,count(t2.items) FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id GROUP BY t1.*

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer:

**Sadly you cannot `group by *`.** BUT instead of grouping you can **try making use of an inner query instead**. See details for example :)

### Details:

There really should be a way to group by all that you have specified in the select statement.

But until that day, there is a clean way to get what you want. Try using an inner query:

So instead of doing this **WHICH DOES NOT WORK**:

```
select c.*, sum(tx.amount) as total_balance
from customer_table c
join transaction_table tx on c.id = tx.user_table_id
group by c.* -- this does not work
```

Use an **inner query**:

```
select c.*,
(select
    sum(tx.amount)
    from transaction_table tx where c.id = tx.user_table_id
)  as total_balance
from customer_table c
```

In my case I had two tables:

1. customer_table for bank accounts that has an "amount" column
2. transaction_table, where the TransactionTable had updated amounts to the user's account.

The problem was that the customer_table.amount column only had the initial amount that the customer opened the bank account with and not the updated amount from all the transactions stored in the transaction_table since opening the account. So I needed to join the transaction_table and sum all transactions for each user.
This means selecting c.* from customer_table, and also the sum of the transactions. This would require joining with transaction table, and group by c.* which is not possible. So... if this was the same situation that you were in, don't use group by, instead use an inner query. :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is my suggestion:

```
DECLARE @FIELDS VARCHAR(MAX), @NUM INT

--DROP TABLE #FIELD_LIST

SET @NUM = 1
SET @FIELDS = ''

SELECT 
'SEQ' = IDENTITY(int,1,1) ,
COLUMN_NAME
INTO #FIELD_LIST
FROM Req.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'new340B'

WHILE @NUM <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #FIELD_LIST)
BEGIN
SET @FIELDS = @FIELDS + ',' + (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM #FIELD_LIST WHERE SEQ = @NUM)
SET @NUM = @NUM + 1
END

SET @FIELDS = RIGHT(@FIELDS,LEN(@FIELDS)-1)

EXEC('SELECT ' + @FIELDS + ', COUNT(*) AS QTY FROM [Req].[dbo].[new340B] GROUP BY ' + @FIELDS + ' HAVING COUNT(*) > 1  ')
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use Group by All but be careful as Group by All will be removed from future versions of SQL server.

Comment: ´Group by All´ has nothing to do with grouping by all columns !