# MySQL SUM OVER PARTITION BY. Is GROUP BY unnecessary?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to understand this SQL code and am unsure of what the `GROUP BY` is doing or if it is even necessary.

```
    SELECT 
        month, 
        year, 
        region,
        SUM(a) OVER (PARTITION BY region, month, year) AS total_a,
        SUM(b) OVER (PARTITION BY region, month, year) AS total_b,
        SUM(c) OVER (PARTITION BY region, month, year) AS total_c
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,a,b,c
```

From my understanding, the grouping for the sum of the window is already indicated by `PARTITION BY`, so I am not sure why the grouping is even needed.

I read from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800910/sql-grouping-by-all-the-columns) that the `GROUP BY` over all columns serves as a way to remove duplicate rows.

Comment: What it is not needed is the partition, you can just do it with the group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `group by` have been added to eliminate duplicates :

Consider this sample data :

```
create table sales (
  month int,
  year int,
  region varchar(10),
  a int,
  b int,
  c int
);

insert into sales values
(1, 2021, 'A', 10, 10, 10),
(1, 2021, 'A', 10, 10, 10), -- this will be eliminated by group by
(2, 2022, 'B', 10, 10, 10),
(2, 2022, 'B', 10, 10, 20);
```

So the query :

```
SELECT 
        month, 
        year, 
        region,
        SUM(a) OVER (PARTITION BY region, month, year) AS total_a,
        SUM(b) OVER (PARTITION BY region, month, year) AS total_b,
        SUM(c) OVER (PARTITION BY region, month, year) AS total_c
FROM sales
GROUP BY 1,2,3,a,b,c
```

Results :

```
month   year    region  total_a total_b total_c
1       2021    A       10      10      10
2       2022    B       20      20      30
2       2022    B       20      20      30
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/WMebPIKe)

Comment: In that case, should it be `GROUP BY 1,2,3a,b,c` or `GROUP BY 1,2,3,total_a,total_b,total_c`?

Comment: This query can be translated as : find any duplicates based on the combination (month, year, region, a, b, c), therefore the group by should be `GROUP BY 1,2,3, a,b,c`.

Comment: Also An alias can't be used on group by, so `GROUP BY 1,2,3,total_a,total_b,total_c` is not allowed